# javafx in eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class D:\javafx\javafx-sdk-20.0.1\lib

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

tryn to setup javafx in the eclipse, but cant seem to get it to work.
[image]

the image show the structure of Java Fx application, but i keep getting the following error, when tryn to run app:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class D:\javafx\javafx-sdk-20.0.1\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: D:\javafx\javafx-sdk-20.0.1\lib
```

I've added the javafx/lib location to my JRE, got the custom user javafx package added, eclipse doesn't show any errors, however app doesnt seem to start..

Comment: Your command line arguments are wrong.  It thinks this `D:\javafx\javafx-sdk-20.0.1\lib` is your main class and obviously it is not.  I do not use Eclipse and will offer no further help.

Comment: In the _Run Configurations_ window, click on the _Show Command Line_ button.